# What is the relationship between Revival and Necromancer badges?

Tags: support, badges

From the Badge help page (on SO):

> **Revival**
>     Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more
>     127.2k awarded
>
> **Necromancer**
>     Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more
>     130.9k awarded

From reading that, I'd have thought that every answer that qualifies for the Necromancer badge also qualifies for the Revival badge.  And yet there are more necromancers than revivalists amongst us?  Can anyone enlighten us on this?

Comment: "as first answer"

Comment: @Mysticial It appears that [a second answer can qualify, if the first answer no longer meets the score requirement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320511/4151918).

Comment: @user4151918 first answer getting +2. If some answer got it before, but later lost it, that makes this answer the first when analysing the thread in its current status.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To earn the **Revival** badge the answer must be the *first* answer to the question.  There is no such restriction for the **Necromancer** badge.

Comment: I proposed a [gold badge for the revival/necromancer pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268), **Persephone**. It would combine both requirements.