# Why did I receive the Revival badge?

Tags: support, badges

Yesterday I received the Revival badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669784/520044). It has been steadily getting upvotes since I posted it four years ago - why should I receive Revival for it at this point in time? The only reason that comes to mind would be if the rules for Revival have recently changed, but I didn't find anything to support that idea ...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It looks like [the first eligible answer which happened to score 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023607/how-to-use-logonuser-properly-to-impersonate-domain-user-from-workgroup-client/8337442#8337442) was downvoted 2 days ago, dropping it to 1.

This made *your* answer the oldest answer with a score of 2 or more.

Technically, you were the *second* answer to score 2 or more, but the badge script apparently doesn't take into account that there was a prior answer which had already earned Revival, and also awarded the badge to you once your answer met the requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I guess, another option could have been deletion of a previous answer.

Comment: In this case, there is no older deleted answer

Comment: Oh, I have always interpreted the rule as "You are first to answer, and your score is 2 or more". Apparently it is "Your answer has score 2 or more, and your answer is the first among all such answers"

Comment: Would be quite difficult to track that as well, without adding a new column to the database table for the question.

Comment: @justhalf The question isn't revived until one of the late answers has scored 2 or more. A question apparently can be revived more than once, if no late answers presently revive it, so it's not even necessarily the first late answer which has done so.

Comment: Does this mean the user who posted the first eligible answer lost their Revival badge?

Comment: No. [Badges aren't revoked unless there was fraud involved in obtaining them.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261259/4151918)  As you can see, [they still have it, even though their score no longer meets the requirement.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival?userid=935352)

Comment: I've just received a revival badge on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26910037/674039) immediately after *downvoting* an existing answer (which was at +2).  So this badge seems to incentivize downvoting other answers competing with your own!